# How is the config symbol resolved in environments/*.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is how a typical `config/environments/*.rb` file begins:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  ...
end
```

The block passed to `configure` dereferences the symbol `config` which is apparently unbound. How does this technically work? The symbols used in a block/Proc/lambda should be bound in the context of its declaration, not left to be resolved in the dynamic scope at the call site.

A related question is, where exactly is the `Application.configure` method declared? It's not in either [`application.rb`](https://raw.github.com/rails/rails/b04ec2764f62d5734c57959e2f00f9ef4345d52e/railties/lib/rails/application.rb), [`engine.rb`](https://raw.github.com/rails/rails/b04ec2764f62d5734c57959e2f00f9ef4345d52e/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb), or [`railtie.rb`](https://raw.github.com/rails/rails/b04ec2764f62d5734c57959e2f00f9ef4345d52e/railties/lib/rails/railtie.rb). Maybe if I managed to find this method, I would have found the answer to my main question.

Also related, I have studied the [Rails initialization procedure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html) in excruciating detail, and I can't find even a mention of a `config/environments/*.rb` file. If I knew how these files were treated by the init procedure, that may shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a method `config` in `Rails::Application` in the railties gem in `lib/rails/application.rb` which returns an instance of `Application::Configuration`, defined in `lib/rails/application/configuration.rb`.

The method `configure` is contributed to `Railtie` from the `autoload`ed module `Configurable`, `lib/rails/railtie/configurable`, and is defined as

```
def configure(&block)
  class_eval(&block)
end
```

which explains why the block that `configure` accepts can resolve the `config` symbol. Note that `class_eval` is another piece of rubyist magic that makes this work: it rebinds the passed-in block's `self` symbol to the call site's class.

Check the comments in the first file in the Booting Process section, which explains where, how and in what order all this goodness comes from, including how the `/config/environments` directory is processed.

Comment: I have checked that file [here](https://raw.github.com/rails/rails/b04ec2764f62d5734c57959e2f00f9ef4345d52e/railties/lib/rails/application.rb), but searching for `configure` reveals nothing. Am I looking at a wrong version?

Comment: To be clear, I can find `config`, but that doesn't explain how the block passed to `configure` can see that method from its declaration context. I am looking for the `configure` method, which is what is being called from `ENV.rb`.

Comment: `lib/rails/railtie/configurable#configure` is the main place this method is defined as `def configure(&block); class_eval(&block);      end.` -- so that's the block you're looking for, right?

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything. `class_eval(&block)`. Can you please edit this into your answer? I still have to inform myself on the `autoload` directive that loaded this file into `railtie.rb`.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason I dug into this was that I had asked myself the same question a few times and never really dug around to figure it out.  (And now I realize another answer I write on SO a few days ago isn't quite right -- blush).

Comment: That's the nice thing about SO---one learns more by answering than asking :) I find it generally important to know exactly what goes on and why because once something fails, that knowledge is going to be put to good use.