# rails config/environments where is 'config' defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In `config/environments/production.rb` (and the other environments) there is:

```
config.eager_load = true
```

and a whole bunch of other `config.foobar` calls. But where does 'config' come from? Usually you have something like:

```
SomeClass.each do | block_variable |
  block_variable.some_method
end
```

but in the case of the mystical 'config' this is not the case, its like a block variable which is not declared anywhere. Opening rails console, when I do:

```
irb(main):001:0> config
NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
Did you mean?  conf
        from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0>
```

and the same result occurs for `app.config`

```
irb(main):002:0> app.config
NoMethodError: undefined method `config' for #<ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x00007fc898d02808>
        from (irb):2
```

How is it possible for ruby to allow calls on 'config'?

Comment: Possible a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424178/how-is-the-config-symbol-resolved-in-environments-rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These classes include the `ActiveSupport::Configurable` module:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Configurable.html

Here is an alternative to implementing this behavior by yourself:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block